# Vue.js Vuex action do not see getter from other module

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, jwt, vuex

Im trying to use getter from other module to get JWT token to my http query, which is looking like that:

```
 ...
    },
    actions: {
        async refreshContactData( state, getters, rootState, rootGetters ) {

            
            
            
            return axios.get('/test', {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + rootGetters['user/getJWT']//the token is a variable which holds the token
                }
              }).then(response => {
                console.log(response)
            })
        }
    },
}
```

my second modlue look like this:

```
//user.js

import axios from "axios"


export default {
    state: {
        jwt: 'asdfasdf',

    },
    getters: {
        getJWT: (state) => {
            console.log("WTF")
            return state.jwt;
          }

    },
    ...
```

its connected with main index.js store file:

```
 //index.js
    
   ...
      modules: {
        user: User,
        contact: Contact
      },
   ...
```

i tried different configuration but im still getting "undefined" error in console:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: Cannot read property 'user/getJWT' of undefined
    at _callee$ (contact.js?7526:54)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js?96cf:63)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?96cf:293)
    at Generator.eval [as next] (runtime.js?96cf:118)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:3)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:25)
    at eval (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:32)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at eval (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:21)
    at Store.refreshContactData (contact.js?7526:47)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actions don't have multiple arguments like getters do.  They have a context argument and a payload argument.  To get the `rootGetters` you can destructure the context argument:

```js
async refreshContactData({ rootGetters }) { // notice the braces
...
}
```

Then `rootGetters` will be defined.